# ImageButton изменение картинки при нажатии

Tags: java, android

Нужна кнопка-картинка "ImageButton", при каждом нажатии на "ImageButton" картинка менялась.
activity_main.xml

```
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
    android:src="@drawable/onoff"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="349dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="58dp"
     />
```

---

```
    //MainActivity
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean flag = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // меняем изображение на кнопке
                if (flag)
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.onoff);
                else
                    // возвращаем первую картинку
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.onoffg);
                flag = !flag;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Подскажите где ошибка? Приложение вылетает. 
Ответ: Забыл инициализацию кнопки. Код рабочий.

Comment: У вас не инициализирован imageButton. Вы получили NPE.

Comment: final ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

Comment: Забыл ) Спасибо.

Comment: Yura Ivanov подскажите пожалуйста, как можно поставить условие. Например. if (imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.onoff) == true) {}  Проверка на том, какая картинка сейчас установлена на кнопке. Т.е imageButton активирована или нет.

Comment: Не стоит так делать. Картинки могут поменяться, или добавиться в будущем - потратите кучу времени в поисках проблемы. У вас же есть flag, вот на него и смотрите.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так сделать:

```java
public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // меняем изображение на кнопке
                if (flag){
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.onoff);
                    flag = false;
                }else{
                    // возвращаем первую картинку
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.onoffg);
                    flag=true;
             }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

взять в фигурные скобки?

```
 else {

                // возвращаем первую картинку
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.cutecat2); 
                flag = !flag; 
    }
```

а то flag = !flag;  получается не в конструкции if-else

Comment: Это не кавычки, а фигурные скобки.

Comment: и флаг нужно инвертировать каждый раз. При каждом нажатии.